# Zebra iMZ220 Print up-to a certain length only (Zebra Objective C SDK)

Tags: objective-c, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I have recently started working with CPCL, and I need to print some text onto to a fixed length of paper. `Is there a way to specify the print length?`

While going through the [documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-link-os-pg-en.pdf) I came across a bit that says if the paper has black bars at the back to mark the beginning and end of each 'label' that would help with printing within a given space. `If I had paper like that, how would I set up the printer to do as such?`

Here is a sample of what I have and it prints fine in `line_print` mode. I just need the printer to continue rolling until the paper is of a certain length:

```
! U1 SETLP 7 1 24
! U1 PAGE-WIDTH 480
! U1 SETBOLD 1 George Martin

! U1 SETBOLD 1 King Of: NeverLand

! U1 SETLP 7 0 24
! U1 SETBOLD 1 Number of Children: 6

! U1 CENTER
! U1 B 128 2 21 100 150 10 P0000009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to have a printer that supports label printing. And a command needs to be passed to it to tell it to detect bars and therefore cut off each print when it detects a bar. To specify a printing length it is best to use ZPL language as it supports more commands and provides more control. The guys at Zebra seem to be more familiar with ZPL since CPCL is now old (and not longer officially supported from what I remember reading up)